# Shortest Euclidean distance between two groups in subset

Tags: r, plyr

I have a largish data frame (50000 points) representing points in 2D collected from biological images. Points are categorised as either red or green and are associated with each other in groups (in the example: cells A-D). A small test data set (MSR_test.csv) can be found [**here**](http://pastebin.com/7Kqb0TqU).

```
require(ggplot2)
cells <- read.csv("MSR_test.csv")
ggplot(cells, aes(X, Y, colour = channel, shape = cell)) + 
   geom_point() +
   scale_colour_manual(values = c("green","red"), name = "channel")
```

I am trying to find a reasonably straight forward way (perhaps involving `plyr`?) to find the Euclidean distance between each green point and its nearest red point within the same ‘cell group’. Whilst I think I have worked out how to do this for an individual grouping (using `rdist` from package `fields`) I can’t seem to work out how to apply a method to my data frame.

Comment: Maybe use the `apply` functions to extract the various grouping subsets and run `rdist` on each in turn, storing the desired distances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason to use `plyr`, but maybe I'm wrong. 
The following code works on your example. I did not use any heavy function to compute the Euclidean distance, mainly because you may have to compute it on a lot of points.

```
green <- subset(cells, channel=="Green")
red <- subset(cells, channel=="Red")
fun_dist <- function(a, M) rowSums( (M - matrix(1,nrow(M),1) %*% as.numeric(a))**2 )
foo <- function(greenrow, matred) {
  subred <- subset(matred, cell == greenrow["cell"], select=c("X","Y"))
  minred <- subred[ which.min(fun_dist(unlist(greenrow[c("X","Y")]),subred)), ]
  return(minred)
}
data.frame( "rbind", apply(green, 1, foo, red) )
```